"::after" of HTML-element not shown
I am testing a small part for a bigger project. It is for a seat reservation in a theatre. I am trying to set up a small popup, which is shown when you hover over a seat. I tried doing so with "::after". The CSS in the repository I linked contains a testing "::after" at the end. My goal is in this step to create a textbox with some seat informations. But this info box is not shown. I can see that there is something going on in the browser inspection tab when I hover over seats. But I can see no changes.


function createSeats(pattern, rows) {
  const seatsContainer = document.getElementById("seats");

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < pattern.length; j++) {
      const seatType = pattern[j] % 2 === 0 ? "seat" : "nothing";

      for (let k = 0; k < pattern[j]; k++) {
        const seatImg = document.createElement("img");
        seatImg.src = `./images/${seatType}.png`;
        seatImg.alt = seatType;
        seatImg.classList.add(seatType);
        seatsContainer.appendChild(seatImg);
      }
    }
  }
}

createSeats([10, 1, 10], 13);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#frame {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#stage {
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#seats {
  --rows: 13;
  --columns: 21;
  display: grid;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), calc(100% / var(--columns)));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), var(--columns));
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.seat {
  /* its an image. rotate 180 degree.  */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
}

.seat.occupied {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.seat::after {
  content: 'Test';
  display: none;
}

.seat:hover::after {
  display: inline;
}

.nothing {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
<h1>Sitzplatz</h1>

<section id="frame">
  <div id="stage">Bühne</div>
  <div id="seats"></div>
</section>




Should be closed as duplicate of Why don't :before and :after pseudo elements work with img elements?

Does this answer your question? Why don't :before and :after pseudo elements work with `img` elements?
